# Script to automate TrueCrypt

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, truecrypt

So I am logging into a windows server and once I login as a administrator a small pop u box of the TrueCrypt comes up and it asks for a TrueCrypt password.Once I provide the password certain files will be mounted.So I am looking for a script which would help me to automate this process.Like every time the server reboots I want to set the password to the TrueCrypt automatically so that the files would be mounted.

I was actually thinking of a powershell script which could be set up in windows Task scheduler and then configure the task to run every time the server restarts.But I am not sure how we can send the password of TrueCrypt using powershell commands.Could you let me know how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't.

You should be moving away from TrueCrypt altogether. It is no longer supported, no longer being developed, and per the creators [may have unpatched security vulnerabilities](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/). Get away from TrueCrypt ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

within your script you could use the"/p" flag to hand over the password. Also "/q background" and "/s" to suppress all warnings or popup windows might help.

Comment: Won't doing this essentially leave the password for your super-secret encrypted volume embedded in the script, in cleartext?

Comment: You could have your script reading the password from a database or central keystore, having it within the script for sure is no good idea ;)

Comment: You're still storing the password in a location and manner which leaves it accessible. If it's in the database, it's readable by anyone with the right level of access to the database.